# DataGrid Edit and Readonly behaviour in wpf

Tags: wpf, datagrid, readonly

I m new to WPf Datagrid  .My requirement if i select a cell in datagrid and press enter it should changed to readonly= false(editable) and user can change the content and again if he press enter key the cell should  change to readonly = true(noneditable).

My xaml look like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="496"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
          PreviewKeyDown="DgvMaterial_PreviewKeyDown" DataGridCell.Selected="DataGrid_select" 
          Name="DgvMaterial" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="958" Margin="21,20,0,0"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}"   
          AlternationCount="1" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFE9FFE9" 
          SelectionUnit="FullRow" CanUserResizeColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding}" 
          RowHeight="30" UseLayoutRounding="True" 
          RowHeaderWidth="0" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" ColumnHeaderHeight="30" 
          SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          FontFamily="MS Gothic" FontSize="12" CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}" 
          IsHitTestVisible="True" SelectionChanged="DgvMaterial_SelectionChanged" 
          Loaded="DgvMaterial_Loaded" CellEditEnding="DgvMaterial_CellEditEnding" TabIndex="5"
          SelectedIndex="-1" IsReadOnly="True">
```

Comment: And the focus should remain in same cell

Comment: did you try to use `DataGridTemplateColumn` and specify `CellTemplate` for view (for example `TextBlock`) and `CellEditingTemplate` for edit (for example `TextBox`)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably what you're looking for is [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which can have 2 templates. One is to show value (`DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`) and the other is used in edit mode (`DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate`):

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ColumnName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ColumnName}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You can specify it per column, not for grid, and by default it will go into edit mode on `F2` or double click but you can handle `DataGrid.PreviewKeyDown` and `BeginEdit()` on `Enter`